# Why does Chrome onerror handler not return full error messages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, error-handling, onerror

Chrome outputs "Script error." and Firefox outputs "ReferenceError: d is not defined"

Run the following code in both browser's console and notice the difference.
Why is Chrome's message not as descriptive as Firefox's?  How can one get a full error message out of chrome?

The code is wrapped in setTimeouts so that they can be ran in the same context for console running and output. The issue also occurs when ran as a script.

```js
// custom global error handler
setTimeout(() => {
  window.onerror = function(message) {
    console.log("Error message: ", message)
    return false
  }
})

// create an error
setTimeout(() => {
  d;
})
```

Comment: @Ivar yes, chrome's error handling does show the full message, but the problem is that the custom onerror handler's message is not the full message in chrome.

Comment: I did with the same result, but just realized that that was the error message and not what was logged.

Comment: [MDN does note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#Notes) that "Script error." is reported when the script is loaded from a different origin to prevent leaking information. Looks like both browsers have a different perception about what counts as a different origin.

Comment: I've see the MDN description for Script error.  It should not apply in this situation.  This behavior is not consistent with chrome docs, for example: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/track-exceptions#handle_runtime_exceptions_using_windowonerror

Comment: The page doesn't mention anything about executing that piece of code in the console. It is executed as part of that document. The (previously) runable snippet also showed that message fine in Chrome.

Comment: The problem happens whether the code is ran in the console or ran via script tags inline or via src.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that runs into this issue. It is known that [webpack can interfere](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765909) with window.onerror in chrome because of the webpack url scheme. In this case using chrome 69.03 and Webpack 3.12.0.

I could not find a workaround for these versions, but proper errors are reported from onerror when running the app from the build instead of in dev mode.